# Why is fs.readFile throwing a syntax error of unexpected token when trying to read a XML file?

Tags: node.js, xml

Trying to learn to convert XML to JSON so I can convert some old cURL commands to a script I've been reading a few Q&As and wrote the following module:

```js
fs = require('fs')
const xmlFle = require('./file.xml')
const parser = require('xml2json')

module.exports = fs.readFile(xmlFle, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) return `err: ${err}`
  try {
    const json = parser.toJson(data)
    console.log('to json ->', json)
  } catch (e) {
    return `Convert fail: ${e}`
  }
})
```

but for some reason I'm thrown:

```
/path/to/file/file.xml:1
<Foo>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

reading through a few Q&As I thought my issue was due to setting `fs` from [Unexpected token < when parsing XML in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433408/unexpected-token-when-parsing-xml-in-nodejs) but that didn't prevent the error.

other referenced:

- [Unexpected token < reading xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934187/unexpected-token-reading-xml-file)
- [“[SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]” when I try to add documents to my Solr index with my Node/Express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135609/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-when-i-try-to-add-documents-to-my-solr-index)
- [Javascript unexpected token '<' when loading XML from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500849/javascript-unexpected-token-when-loading-xml-from-model)

file.xml:

```
<Foo>
  <Mon>
    <Auth>326478326472347823</Auth>
    <Signal>foo</Signal>
  </Mon>
  <Feed>
    <Tag>biochemistry</Tag>
  </Feed>
</Foo>
```

I'm not having an issue with the actual conversion:

```
const parser = require('xml2json')
const xml = `<Foo>
<Mon>
  <Auth>326478326472347823</Auth>
  <Signal>foo</Signal>
</Mon>
<Feed>
  <Tag>biochemistry</Tag>
</Feed>
</Foo>`
console.log('JSON output', parser.toJson(xml))
```

results:

```
JSON output {"Foo":{"Mon":{"Auth":"326478326472347823","Signal":"foo"},"Feed":{"Tag":"biochemistry"}}}
```

Why am I getting an error when trying to read the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to `require()` an XML file, which executes the XML as if it was JSON/JavaScript.

You need to pass the path `./file.xml` as a String, but running `require('./file.xml')` reads it and treats it as code.

Replace the `require('./file.xml')` with `'./file.xml'`.